# Pagination in Laravel 4 works for one page. but not working for another

Tags: php, mysql, pagination, laravel, laravel-4

I downloaded the starter kit for laravel using sentry from GitHub.

Everything is fine so far. Blog page has pagination. I am able to change the number of items per page as I like by changing the same pagination(x) value.

Now problem is, i created a new page manually by myself called "Search" which displays results for Keywords searched.

Here I added the same pagination, it shows the number of items per page as mentioned, page numbers, arrows. Everything is perfect, but when I click page 2 it shows a BLANK PAGE. The page source of blank page is also empty. The URL is perfect for page two. It generates correctly as

`sitename.dev/search?page=2`

Please guide me where I am going wrong. The blog page pagination still works fine. Problem occurs only in newly created SEARCH page pagination.

This is my Controller

```
public function postSearch()
{
    $searchString = Input::get('searchInput');

    $posts = Post::where('title', 'LIKE', '%' . $searchString . '%')->orderBy('created_at', 'DESC')->paginate(4);

    if($searchString){

    return View::make('frontend/search', compact('posts'))->with('success', 'Account successfully updated')->with('posts', $posts);
    }
    else{
        return Redirect::route('home')->with('error', 'Please enter Search Term');
    }

}
```

This is my Route

```
Route::any('/search', 'BlogController@postSearch');
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all

```
return View::make('frontend/search', compact('posts'))->with('success', 'Account successfully updated')->with('posts', $posts);
```

When doing `compact` you're already including the `$posts` var to be used as `$posts` in the view, exactly the same you'd do using `with('posts', $posts)`. So this last can be removed. If you want to load more vars using `compact` just separe the variable names by commas.

You're paginating the item in the `POST` action of `Search`, when you click any of the pagination links or call `page=2` you're not running the `postSearch` method, you're probably calling `getSearch` as you're not doing now a `POST` request.

Have a look to [RESTful controllers](http://laravel.com/docs/controllers#restful-controllers)

Comment: ok, but is there any way to get the &search=SEARCHTERM in the Page1 of the search too?

I already get it from Page2. 

Page1 simple shows as site.dev/search

If users bookmark this link, they wont get results in future

Comment: Send your form via GET method

Comment: changed my route from "any" to "get"
in this case I get
Symfony \ Component \ HttpKernel \ Exception \ MethodNotAllowedHttpException

Comment: I meant your form method to GET. Read the link I posted above.

Comment: {{ Form::open(array('url'=>'search', 'class' => 'form-search form-horizontal pull-right', 'id' => 'custom-search-form')) }}

this is my form code. How to specify GET in form method. I am new to Laravel as well as PHP. Please dont mistake me

Comment: Add `method=>'GET'` to that array and you'll see it adds all the form field values to the URL. Using this method you will call the `getSearch` function instead the `postSearch`. Try it out

Comment: Really thanks alot. You made my 3 days issue solved very easily.

Comment: One more thing,

Is there a way to get pretty URL for the same?
my page one looks like "http://sitename.dev/search?search=Lorem" and page 2 looks like "sitename.dev/search?page=2&search=Lorem"

Something like sitename.dev/search/lorem/2/ looks very pretty

Comment: You'd have to play with routes. If these are your first steps on Laravel, I'd recommend to wait a little bit more and have a bit more framework knowledge. Anyway, take a look to routing at the documentation, you'll easy understand how it works ;)

Comment: I thought pretty URLs work with .htaccess. Route just tells which view to be used on a post or get method. Am I wrong?

I tried some .htaccess examples but they did not work and hence I posted here

Answer (score 6):

Search form better using GET method, because it's make easy to bookmark/save the URL for later use. In Laravel 4's Pagination, there's a method to appends the query string. So, we can keep the search querystring in other pages.

Docs:
http://laravel.com/docs/pagination#appending-to-pagination-links

My code:

**Search Form**

```
<form method="get" action="{{{ URL::to('lib/search') }}}">
<input class="input-xxlarge" name="q" type="text" placeholder="Search...">
<div class="control-group">
    <div class="controls">
        <input type="submit" class="btn" id="submit" value="Submit" />
    </div>
</div>
```

**Routing**

```
Route::get('lib/search', 'LibraryController@getSearch');
```

**Controller**

```
public function getSearch()
{
    $search = Input::get('q');

    $posts = $this->post->where('title', 'like', '%'.$search.'%')->paginate(10);

    return View::make('site/libraries/list', compact('posts', 'search'));
}
```

**View / Blade**
At method to display pagination:

```
{{ $posts->appends(array('q' => $search))->links() }}
```

So we can keep the **q=?** querystring in other pages (ex: /lib/search?page=2&q=apple)

Comment: Thank you, this answer helped me, +1. But with Laravel 5.1 I added `{!! $users->appends($filters)->render() !!}` instead of `->links()` in View and `$users->setPath('search');` in Model, after queryng and saving filters in `$filters` array.

Answer (score 0):

A few things to check.

1. The new route exists in the `app/routes.php` file.
2. You are returning a view file for the new route.
3. That view file has the pagination output. For example: `<?php echo $articles->links(); ?>`.

Ultimately, there appears to be some kind of error occurring, which is why the page is rendering blank. Trying turning php errors on in your dev env and see what happens after that.

Comment: The problem was with the Get / Post method. after I changed it to any it is working for page 2. But it shows all results from database. Where as first page particularly shows only the Searched Keyword. 

As per my knowledge, it is taking first page as POST, but second page gets converted into GET method

Answer (score 0):

appends solved my issue. Also usage of appends will enable our users to save/bookmark the URL for future use.

But one problem is, it is not appending First page of the result.