# Laravel PHP: Additional Pagination Pages of results not being retrieved properly

Tags: php, laravel-4

I'm working on a Laravel PHP application where on the home page, the user selects a particular category and results are returned after the user makes their selection.  Right now results are being returned properly except for one issue where if there are multiple pages of results.

For example, let's say I have 15 records that belong to 'category1'.  Right now I have the pagination set up so that 10 results are displayed per page.  So these 15 records should be displayed as follows, Page 1 contains 10 records and Page 2 contains 5 records.  However the problem I'm having is that Page 1 displays the first 10 records for the selected category fine but when selecting Page 2, it displays ALL of the additional records and not just the remaining 5 records that belong to 'category1'.

**Controller:**

```
 <!-- Form -->

 {{Form::model(array('method' => 'GET', 'route' => 'overview_select', 'files' => true)) }}    

 <div class="form-group">
 {{ Form::label('category', 'Category:') }}
 {{ Form::select('category', array('category1' => 'Category1', 'category2' => 'Category2', 'category3' => 'Category3', 'category4' => 'Category4'), (isset($category) ? $category : 'category')) }}

 <div class="form-group">
 {{ Form::submit('Select Category', array('class' => 'btn btn-primary')) }}
 </div>

 {{ Form::close() }}

 </div>

   public function index()
{
    $vdo = Video::query();
    $pic = Picture::query();
    if($category = Input::get('category')){
        $vdo->where('category', $category);
        $pic->where('category', $category);
    }

    $allvids = $vdo->paginate(10);
    $allpics = $pic->paginate(10);
    $data = compact('allvids','allpics');
    $data['category'] = Input::get('category');
    $this->layout->content = \View::make('home.pics_vids_overview',$data);
}
```

**View:**

```
<div class="panel-body">
            @if ($allvids->count())
                <dl class="dl-horizontal">
                    <!-- Add this div class to make the table responsive -->
                    <div class = "table-responsive">
                        <table class="table">
                            <b>Results: </b>{{ $allvids->count() }}<br>
                            <tr>
                                <th>ID</th>
                                <th>Name</th>
                                <th>Description</th>
                                <th>Corner</th>
                                <th>Rock</th>
                                <th>Category</th>
                                <th>Project</th>
                                <th>Update Video</th>
                            </tr>        
                    @foreach($allvids as $video)
                    <tr>
                         <td>{{ $video->video_id }}</b></td>
                         <td>{{ $video->video_name }}</td>
                         <td>{{ $video->video_description }}</td>
                         <td>{{ $video->video_corners }} </td>
                         <td>{{ $video->video_rocks }}</td>
                         <td>{{ $video->category }}</td>
                         <td>{{ $video->video_project }}</td>

                         <td><b>{{ link_to_route("show_video", 'Edit', array($video->video_id)) }}</b></td>
                    </tr>     
                    @endforeach
                    {{ $allvids-> links()}}
                        </table>
                    </div>    


                </dl>
            @else
                <b>{{ 'No Videos in this category.' }}</b>
            @endif
        </div>
```

**Routes.php**

```
Route::post('pics_vids', array('as'=>'overview_select', 'uses' => 'OverviewController@index'));

Route::get('pics_vids', array('as'=>'overview', 'uses' => 'OverviewController@index'));
```

I'm not quite sure if I need to append anything within my controller in order for additional pages to only display results from the selected category.  Any help is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe the problem is in your process of retrieving the pagination based on *category* . It is better to use GET method to retrieve listing results, because using POST method for pagination listing might throw *form resubmission* warning in some browsers when users hit back button.

Now, the reason you are getting all the products in page 2 is

```
   if($category = Input::get('category')){
    $vdo->where('category', $category);
    $pic->where('category', $category);
}
```

Here, when the second link is clicked, the request is not POSTed anymore, so the *Input::get()* method is empty. Change the routing so that the *category* forms as a part of URL, either in the form of query string or URI string.

EDIT:

I changed the form in the view from:

```
{{Form::model(array('method' => 'GET', 'route' => 'overview_select', 'files' => true)) }}
```

to:

```
{{Form::open(array('method' => 'GET', 'route' => 'overview_select', 'files' => true)) }}
```

So now the 'category' field will appear in the URL after the user makes their selection.

In the view, I changed

```
{{ $allvids-> links()}}
```

to:

```
{{ $allvids->appends(array('category' => $category))->links()}}
```

And now the pagination will work for additional pages.

The link below helped me out with my solution and also gives a good explanation on how GET/POST methods work in forms for Laravel 4.

[Pagination in Laravel 4 works for one page, but not working for another](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17451963/pagination-in-laravel-4-works-for-one-page-but-not-working-for-another)

Comment: I'm having trouble implementing your suggestion.  When you say to change the routing, do you mean my actual routes for my overview pages in (routes.php) or how my views are constructed within my controller?

Comment: One thing I changed in my Form code was I changed 'Form::method(...)' to 'Form::open(...)' and now when I select a category, it actually appears in the URL only for the first page.  Now I just have to figure out so that it'll appear in the URL for additional pages.

Comment: Ok I figured out a solution to my problem by using the 'appends()' method to my 'links()' method within my view.  I'm going to edit your solution above @Miraz, thank you so much!